# Image location won't write to file and Image won't load from file location

Tags: vb.net, string, image, object

well I want to make the program write a an image location to a text file, and then when the user presses the "load" button, it reads that image location and sets it as the Image of the PictureBox, but so far I have had no success at all.

```
Private Sub Btn_Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Save.Click
    Dim path As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures + "\Card Library\Configs\" + "config_card.aygo"
    Dim path2 As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures + "\Card Library\Configs\" + "set_cardimg.aygo"

    ' Create or overwrite the file. 
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
    Dim fs2 As FileStream = File.Create(path2)

    ' Add text to the file. 
    Dim info As Byte() =
        New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(
            "----------Saved Card Settings----------" + vbNewLine +
            "Level: " + My.Settings.Level.ToString + vbNewLine +
            "NoMonster: " + My.Settings.NoMonster.ToString + vbNewLine +
            "Spell: " + My.Settings.Spell.ToString + vbNewLine +
            "Trap: " + My.Settings.Trap.ToString + vbNewLine +
            "XYZLevel: " + My.Settings.XyzLevel.ToString + vbNewLine +
            "ATKValue: " + My.Settings.ATKValue.ToString + vbNewLine +
            "DEFValue: " + My.Settings.DEFValue.ToString + vbNewLine +
            "AttributeID: " + My.Settings.AttributeID.ToString + vbNewLine +
            "CardID: " + My.Settings.CardID.ToString)
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
    fs.Close()
    Dim info2 As Byte() =
        New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(CardImage.InitialImage.ToString)
    fs2.Write(info2, 0, info2.Length)
    fs2.Close()
    MsgBox("Configuration saved successfully!", vbInformation)
End Sub

Private Sub Btn_Load_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Load.Click
    Dim path As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures + "\Card Library\Configs\" + "config_card.aygo"
    Try
        My.Settings.Level = CInt(GetSettingItem(path, "level"))
        My.Settings.NoMonster = CInt(GetSettingItem(path, "nomonster"))
        My.Settings.Spell = CBool(GetSettingItem(path, "spell"))
        My.Settings.Trap = CBool(GetSettingItem(path, "trap"))
        If My.Settings.NoMonster = 1 Then
            If My.Settings.Spell = True Then
                CardFt.Card_Spell()
            Else
                If My.Settings.Trap = True Then
                    CardFt.Card_Trap()
                Else
                    CardFt.Card_Legendary()
                End If
            End If
        End If

        My.Settings.XyzLevel = CInt(GetSettingItem(path, "xyzlevel"))
        If My.Settings.XyzLevel = 1 Then
            CardFt.Card_XYZ()
        End If

        My.Settings.ATKValue = GetSettingItem(path, "atkvalue")
        ATKText.Text = GetSettingItem(path, "atkvalue")

        My.Settings.DEFValue = GetSettingItem(path, "defvalue")
        DEFText.Text = GetSettingItem(path, "defvalue")

        My.Settings.AttributeID = CInt(GetSettingItem(path, "attributeid"))
        If My.Settings.AttributeID = 1 Then
            AttributeLayer.Image = My.Resources.Earth
        ElseIf My.Settings.AttributeID = 2 Then
            AttributeLayer.Image = My.Resources.Water
        ElseIf My.Settings.AttributeID = 3 Then
            AttributeLayer.Image = My.Resources.Fire
        ElseIf My.Settings.AttributeID = 4 Then
            AttributeLayer.Image = My.Resources.Wind
        ElseIf My.Settings.AttributeID = 5 Then
            AttributeLayer.Image = My.Resources.Dark
        ElseIf My.Settings.AttributeID = 6 Then
            AttributeLayer.Image = My.Resources.Light
        ElseIf My.Settings.AttributeID = 7 Then
            AttributeLayer.Image = My.Resources.Divine
        End If

        My.Settings.CardID = CInt(GetSettingItem(path, "cardid"))
        CardFt.Card_Loader()


        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures + "\Card Library\Configs\" + "set_cardimg.aygo") Then
            Try
                Dim fileReader As String
                fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures + "\Card Library\Configs\" + "set_cardimg.aygo")
            Catch ex As Exception : End Try
        End If

        Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures + "Card Library\Configs\" + "set_cardimg.aygo")
        CardImage.Image = CType(bitmap, System.Drawing.Image)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occured while loading the configuration file: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ex.ToString, vbExclamation)
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The error that I get from this is:

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
>      at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)
>      at AnimeYuGiOhCardMaker.CardMaker.Btn_Load_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Compusys\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Anime Yu-Gi-Oh Card Maker\Anime Yu-Gi-Oh Card Maker\Form1.vb:line 521

Now then, when the Save Button is being pressed It does not write the image location to file however it writes the following:

> System.Drawing.Bitmap

This is why I get the error above.
The actual error is from here:

> Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures + "Card Library\Configs\" + "set_cardimg.aygo")
>               CardImage.Image = CType(bitmap, System.Drawing.Image)

The error occurs even with an actual file path.

I tried a few different ways but none of them worked. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

--
Dom

Comment: why are you manually writing `Settings` to a text file?  what line is the error on? cant you tell which image to restore from `My.Settings.AttributeID`?

Comment: @Plutonix I'm manually using settings, because I don't want the built in settings to be saved, so I have to use an external file. The error is on the MsgBox in Catch ex As Exception. My.Settings.AttributeID images are stored in My.Resources so they work fine and so does My.Settings.CardID. However, CardImage(Which is a Picturebox) loads an image the user has chosen so it is external, and I need to be able to write that filepath to a text file and vise verse, when the user loads it, the image will be restored/loaded from that file path

Comment: @Plutonix I have just updated the post you may want to look at it again

Comment: a) the exception is **not** in the Catch - that is just where your code **reports** it b) since `Settings` are likely being saved automatically anyway, just add a User setting for the file location.  You keep changing (not updating) the post and even the error has changed, but `"set_cardimg.aygo"` is not the name of a valid bitmap - that is the name of the settings file you were trying to create.  You also have an empty Catch there

Comment: I set it so that My.Settings are **not** saved on shutdown, because I don't want them to save for a specific reason, however if the user does want to save it, then I want it to save to an external file so that my.settings are reset to default on start up. I just had an idea, is there a way to actually save the file from the Picturebox into the location and then loading the actual image that's been saved in that location back into the program? And what do you mean empty catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question has changed several times, including the exception.  The current state of the question has several problems, the main one being this:

```
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures + "\Card Library\Configs\" + "set_cardimg.aygo") Then
        Try
            Dim fileReader As String
            fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures _
               + "\Card Library\Configs\" + "set_cardimg.aygo")

        ' EMPTY CATCH !!!!!!
        Catch ex As Exception : End Try   
    End If

    Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures _ 
        + "Card Library\Configs\" + "set_cardimg.aygo")
    CardImage.Image = CType(bitmap, System.Drawing.Image)
```

`set_cardimg.aygo` is just a config file which contains some text.  it is not a valid image file, so you cannot create a bitmap from it.

You should open that file, read the contents into a variable, then if it is a valid location, create the bitmap from it, or better just set the picturebox .Location and let it load the image without you creating a bitmap first.

Comment: I understand, so it would be a whole lot easier just to directly load the file. I think I got it to work now, thank you very much for clarifying this to me.

Comment: either way, the filename in the `.aygo` has to exist, so do test for that.  But as for loading I dont see any advantage to manually creating a bitmap from it when/if the PBox will do it for you and properly dispose of the resource when it is done with it.

Comment: Then I guess it would just be the best for the Picturebox to do it, right?